# Sitecatalyst linking problems

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build, linker

I have added the Sitecatalyst library to my iPhone application. However I get a lot of linker warnings that I do not know how to get rid of? I am using Xcode 4.2. The deployment target is iOS 4.0. Valid architectures are set to arm6 & arm7.

Example:

*ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../libAppMeasurement-iOSDevice.a, missing required architecture i386 in file*

**How do I get rid of these warnings? Are the warnings any harmful?**

(From experiences, warnings like these sooner or later get you into trouble.)

Comment: looks like the library was built for the device and you're trying to run it on the simulator.

Comment: There are two libraries; one for the device and one for the simulator. Both have linker warnings.

Comment: Rog 4; thanks, your answer made me think a little bit. As it turns out you need to add one or the other, not both. With my settings, Xcode will try to link both. I now manually delete the one that I am not using and adding the one that I need. During my daily work I switch quite often between the simulator and the phone. Now I need a way for Xcode to find out which one to use depending on the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there was a newer version of the Sitecatalyst library that was built the correct way.